# Android Peer to Peer connection for Wireless Hotspot with Login web page

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, p2p

We can convert any android device into a WiFi hotspot, We can also create the peer to peer connection to transfer the data. Can we do it following things:

- Device A becomes the WiFi Hotspot
- Device B connects the Device A
- Device B will get the login webpage
- Device B needs to fill login detail to use the internet.

We can accomplish similar scenario with Router and windows software like ARPMiner, Can we do it with Android?

Comment: interesting....

Comment: any news or solutions ? did u find something?